# Need help understanding error ORA-00904 in SQL. I keep getting this error message on my proj_task table. The first 3 tables are created successfully

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE project_dept 
(proj_dept_id number(4,0) NOT NULL,
 proj_dept_name varchar2(40) NOT NULL,
 office_location varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
 phone_number varchar2(12) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT project_dept_pk PRIMARY KEY (proj_dept_id)
);

CREATE TABLE employees 
(employee_id number(2,0) NOT NULL,
 first_name varchar2(40) NOT NULL,
 last_name varchar2(40) NOT NULL,
 proj_dept_id number(4) NOT NULL,
 phone_number varchar(12),
 email varchar2(20),
 CONSTRAINT employees_pk PRIMARY KEY (employee_id),
 CONSTRAINT fk_proj_dept
     FOREIGN KEY (proj_dept_id)
     REFERENCES project_dept(proj_dept_id)
);

CREATE TABLE project_data
(project_id number(3,0) NOT NULL,
 proj_name varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
 proj_dept_id number(4,0) NOT NULL,
 max_hours number(3,0) NOT NULL,
 startdate date,
 enddate date,
 CONSTRAINT project_data_pk PRIMARY KEY (project_id),
 CONSTRAINT fk_project_dept
     FOREIGN KEY (proj_dept_id)
     REFERENCES project_dept (proj_dept_id)
);

CREATE TABLE proj_task
(proj_id number (3,0) NOT NULL,
 employee_id number (2,0) NOT NULL,
 task_details varchar2(100),
 hours_worked number(2,0),
 CONSTRAINT proj_task_pk PRIMARY KEY (proj_id, employee_id),
 CONSTRAINT proj_id_fk 
     FOREIGN KEY (proj_id) 
     REFERENCES project_data_pk (project_id),
 CONSTRAINT employee_id_fk 
     FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) 
     REFERENCES employees_pk (employee_id),
);
```

Comment: ORA-<some number> errors as well as the data type `varchar2` indicate that you use Oracle not MySQL, am I right? You should [edit] the question and change the tag from MySQL to Oracle then.

Answer (score 0):

You have an additional comma after the last constraint which doesn't belong there. And `REFERENCES` clauses are in the form of `REFERENCES <table name> (<column names>)` the primary key or unique constraint name isn't use there.

```
CREATE TABLE proj_task
(proj_id number (3,0) NOT NULL,
 employee_id number (2,0) NOT NULL,
 task_details varchar2(100),
 hours_worked number(2,0),
 CONSTRAINT proj_task_pk PRIMARY KEY (proj_id, employee_id),
 CONSTRAINT proj_id_fk 
     FOREIGN KEY (proj_id) 
     REFERENCES project_data (project_id),
 CONSTRAINT employee_id_fk 
     FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) 
     REFERENCES employees (employee_id)
);
```